# assign values to Rank in a poker game

Tags: java, poker

How do you assign values to Rank in a poker game. I have the name Ranks of the cards and they are stored in a Collection method, but I cant figure out how to pull out the values and assign them a digit number value.

private Collection cards; // so this is my hands and I have my cards stored here, but now I wanna pull them out and assign them digit values.

Thanks!

Update: I am trying to compare the ranks of the cards.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in the least. [Ask]

Comment: Computers use numbers. Programmers decide how to represent bits of the real world with numbers. That's your job, and its entirely up to you, based on what functions you need to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enum`s to store your cards' Rank (DUECE to ACE) and Suit (CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES)

Something like this:

```
enum Suit{
    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;
}

enum Rank {
    DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE;
}
```

`Card` can be a class that has each of a Rank and Suit:

```
public class Card{
    Rank rank;
    Suit suit;

    Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        ...
    }

}
```

If you need a value for each rank, add a method to `enum Rank` so that it returns value. Like this:

```
enum Rank {
    DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE;

    public int value() {
        return this.ordinal() + 2; // This will return 2 for DEUCE, 3 for THREE and so on..
    }
}
```

--

Hope this helps!